# Flink SQL Client connect to secured kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-sql

I want to execute a query on Flink SQL Table backed by kafka topic of secured kafka cluster. I'm able to execute the query programmatically but unable to do the same through Flink SQL client. I'm not sure on how to pass JAAS config (`java.security.auth.login.config`) and other system properties through Flink SQL client.

**Flink SQL query programmatically**

```
 private static void simpleExec_auth() {

        // Create the execution environment.
        final EnvironmentSettings settings = EnvironmentSettings.newInstance()
                .inStreamingMode()
                .withBuiltInCatalogName(
                        "default_catalog")
                .withBuiltInDatabaseName(
                        "default_database")
                .build();

        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config","client_jaas.conf");
        System.setProperty("sun.security.jgss.native", "true");
        System.setProperty("sun.security.jgss.lib", "/usr/libexec/libgsswrap.so");
        System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly","false");

        TableEnvironment tableEnvironment = TableEnvironment.create(settings);
        String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE  test_flink11 ( " + "`keyid` STRING, " + "`id` STRING, "
                + "`name` STRING, " + "`age` INT, " + "`color` STRING, " + "`rowtime` TIMESTAMP(3) METADATA FROM 'timestamp', " + "`proctime` AS PROCTIME(), " + "`address` STRING) " + "WITH ( "
                + "'connector' = 'kafka', "
                + "'topic' = 'test_flink10', "
                + "'scan.startup.mode' = 'latest-offset', "
                + "'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka01.nyc.com:9092', "
                + "'value.format' = 'avro-confluent', "
                + "'key.format' = 'avro-confluent', "
                + "'key.fields' = 'keyid', "
                + "'value.fields-include' = 'EXCEPT_KEY', "
                + "'properties.security.protocol' = 'SASL_PLAINTEXT', 'properties.sasl.kerberos.service.name' = 'kafka', 'properties.sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd' = '/usr/local/bin/skinit --quiet', 'properties.sasl.mechanism' = 'GSSAPI', "
                + "'key.avro-confluent.schema-registry.url' = 'http://kafka-schema-registry:5037', "
                + "'key.avro-confluent.schema-registry.subject' = 'test_flink6', "
                + "'value.avro-confluent.schema-registry.url' = 'http://kafka-schema-registry:5037', "
                + "'value.avro-confluent.schema-registry.subject' = 'test_flink4')";
        System.out.println(createQuery);
        tableEnvironment.executeSql(createQuery);
        TableResult result = tableEnvironment
                .executeSql("SELECT name,rowtime FROM test_flink11");
        result.print();
    }
```

This is working fine.

**Flink SQL query through SQL client**

Running this giving the following error.

```
Flink SQL> CREATE TABLE test_flink11 (`keyid` STRING,`id` STRING,`name` STRING,`address` STRING,`age` INT,`color` STRING) WITH('connector' = 'kafka', 'topic' = 'test_flink10','scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset','properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka01.nyc.com:9092','value.format' = 'avro-confluent','key.format' = 'avro-confluent','key.fields' = 'keyid', 'value.avro-confluent.schema-registry.url' = 'http://kafka-schema-registry:5037', 'value.avro-confluent.schema-registry.subject' = 'test_flink4', 'value.fields-include' = 'EXCEPT_KEY', 'key.avro-confluent.schema-registry.url' = 'http://kafka-schema-registry:5037', 'key.avro-confluent.schema-registry.subject' = 'test_flink6', 'properties.security.protocol' = 'SASL_PLAINTEXT', 'properties.sasl.kerberos.service.name' = 'kafka', 'properties.sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd' = '/usr/local/bin/skinit --quiet', 'properties.sasl.mechanism' = 'GSSAPI');

Flink SQL> select * from test_flink11;
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is /tmp/jaas-6309821891889949793.conf
```

There is nothing in `/tmp/jaas-6309821891889949793.conf` except the following comment

```
# We are using this file as an workaround for the Kafka and ZK SASL implementation
# since they explicitly look for java.security.auth.login.config property
# Please do not edit/delete this file - See FLINK-3929
```

**SQL client run command**

```
bin/sql-client.sh embedded --jar  flink-sql-connector-kafka_2.11-1.12.0.jar  --jar flink-sql-avro-confluent-registry-1.12.0.jar
```

**Flink cluster command**

```
bin/start-cluster.sh
```

How to pass this `java.security.auth.login.config` and other system properties (that I'm setting in the above java code snippet), for SQL client?

Comment: did you get any solution @Markiv?

Answer (score 0):

flink-conf.yaml

```
security.kerberos.login.use-ticket-cache: true
security.kerberos.login.principal: XXXXX@HADOOP.COM
security.kerberos.login.use-ticket-cache: false
security.kerberos.login.keytab: /path/to/kafka.keytab
security.kerberos.login.principal: XXXX@HADOOP.COM
security.kerberos.login.contexts: Client,KafkaClient
```

I haven't really tested whether this solution is feasible, you can try it out, hope it will help you.