# When my Flink SQL uses Kafka with Kerberos authentication and submits it to yarn, why does it always fail to pass Kafka authentication?

Tags: apache-flink, kerberos

Using the Kafka data source with Kerberos authentication on Flink SQL, the local test of Flink has passed, but when I push the task to yarn, the error message prompts the problem that the JAAS file of Kafka cannot be found!

Flink SQL related codes are as follows:

```sql
create table source_sensor(
        id VARCHAR,
        ts bigint,
        vc double)
    WITH (
        'connector' = 'kafka',
        'topic' = 'huangfu_0110',
        'scan.startup.mode' = 'latest-offset',
        'properties.group.id' = '1',
        'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '10.0.120.23:9092',
        'properties.security.protocol' = 'SASL_PLAINTEXT',
        'properties.sasl.mechanism' = 'GSSAPI',
        'properties.sasl.kerberos.service.name' = 'kafka',
        'properties.sasl.kerberos.principal.to.local.rules' = 'kafka/cdh-test-1@CDH.COM',
        'properties.sasl.sasl.jaas.config' = 'com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required useKeyTab=true storeKey=true keyTab=\"/ddmp/kafka/kafka.keytab\" principal=\"kafka/cdh-test-1@CDH.COM\";',
        'format' = 'json',
        'json.ignore-parse-errors' = 'true',
        'json.fail-on-missing-field' = 'false'
    );

create table sink_sensor(
        id VARCHAR,
        ts bigint,
        vc double)
    WITH (
        'connector'='jdbc',
        'url'='jdbc:mysql://10.0.10.118:3306/yf1?useSSL=true',
        'table-name'='sink_table',
        'username'='root',
        'password'='123456',
        'sink.buffer-flush.interval'='10s',
        'sink.buffer-flush.max-rows'='10000'
    );
insert into sink_sensor select * from source_sensor;
```

**After submitting, Flink reports the following errors**

```
org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
    at org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:820) ~[byit-flink-sql-engine.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:666) ~[byit-flink-sql-engine.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:646) ~[byit-flink-sql-engine.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.KafkaPartitionDiscoverer.initializeConnections(KafkaPartitionDiscoverer.java:55) ~[byit-flink-sql-engine.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.AbstractPartitionDiscoverer.open(AbstractPartitionDiscoverer.java:94) ~[byit-flink-sql-engine.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.open(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:551) ~[byit-flink-sql-engine.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:34) ~[byit-flink-sql-engine.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.open(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:102) ~[byit-flink-sql-engine.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(OperatorChain.java:426) ~[byit-flink-sql-engine.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$beforeInvoke$2(StreamTask.java:535) ~[byit-flink-sql-engine.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:93) ~[byit-flink-sql-engine.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.beforeInvoke(StreamTask.java:525) ~[byit-flink-sql-engine.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:565) ~[byit-flink-sql-engine.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:755) [byit-flink-sql-engine.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:570) [byit-flink-sql-engine.jar:4.1.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_211]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is /yarn/nm/usercache/ddmp/appcache/application_1642585778653_0040/jaas-2809721433806366634.conf
    at org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.defaultContext(JaasContext.java:133) ~[byit-flink-sql-engine.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.load(JaasContext.java:98) ~[byit-flink-sql-engine.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.loadClientContext(JaasContext.java:84) ~[byit-flink-sql-engine.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:124) ~[byit-flink-sql-engine.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:67) ~[byit-flink-sql-engine.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:99) ~[byit-flink-sql-engine.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:741) ~[byit-flink-sql-engine.jar:4.1.1]
    ... 15 more
```

**All the file paths in the configuration file in Flink SQL and the local directory exist**

The error I observed is that when connecting Kafka, he always looks for a file in the [/yarn/nm/usercache/ddmp/appcache/application_1642585778653_0040/jaas-2809721433806366634.conf] directory, which is very strange

I would appreciate it if you could help me solve it!

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by the flink cluster kerberos configuration. Just need to set some config on flink-conf.yaml can make it work fine!

The settings is below:

```
security.kerberos.login.use-ticket-cache: false 
security.kerberos.login.keytab: /etc/kafka/kafka.keytab
security.kerberos.login.principal: kafka@HADOOP.COM
security.kerberos.login.contexts: Client,KafkaClient
```

Similar question: [Flink SQL Client connect to secured kafka cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66328240/flink-sql-client-connect-to-secured-kafka-cluster)